# Get file names of images that are included in project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, project

I have added many images to my Xcode project: icons, a main background, default (for splash screen), placeholders, and others. Can I get all these images' names into an array?

Answer (score 6):

This should return an array of all your pngs in your app folder.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
```

Note* The array contains paths. If you just want the name use `- (NSString *)lastPathComponent` on a specific index of that array, i.e.

```
NSString *imgName = [[imgArray objectAtIndex:0]lastPathComponent]; //myImage.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply, please can you also tell me if i want to get specific images like bg1, bg2, bg3, bg4, bg5

Comment: Well if you already know the name of the image you want you could do `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"]` or just `UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg1.png"]`

Comment: I have moved all the required images into a directory and giving the name in inDirectory:@"needed_imgs" but i am getting nothing

Comment: Add the folder (with your images) to your project and select `Create folder references ...` that should make it work.

Comment: create folder reference? sorry i didn't get it.

Comment: NSArray *ar = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"viewBg"];

Comment: this what i am doing but not getting anything

Comment: Drag the folder that contains your images (from your desktop or wherever it is) to your Xcode project and drop it inside your project folder. When it prompts you what to do with it select `Create folder references for any added folders`